# ajax request goes but doesn't get any value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
/* ----------- gradeMe -----------*/
function gradeMe () {
  console.log('I am here')
  var graderLink = 'https://inboundgrader.spacek.org/grader.php?website=' + window.Hayk.websiteUrl
  console.log(graderLink)
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://inboundgrader.spacek.org/grader.php?website=' + window.Hayk.websiteUrl
  }).success(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
    window.Hayk.grade = data.grade
    $('div').text(window.Hayk.grade)
  }).error(function (error) {
  $('div').text('error',error)
  console.log('error',error)
  })
}
window.Hayk = {}
window.Hayk.websiteUrl = 'incredo.co'
$('div').on('click', gradeMe)
```

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background:black;
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>clickMe</div>
```

Hi guys so I have this function.

```
/* ----------- gradeMe -----------*/
function gradeMe () {
  console.log('I am here')
  var graderLink = 'https://inboundgrader.spacek.org/grader.php?website=' + window.Hayk.websiteUrl
  console.log(graderLink)
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://inboundgrader.spacek.org/grader.php?website=' + window.Hayk.websiteUrl
  }).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
    window.Hayk.grade = data.grade
  })
  // $.get(graderLink, function (data) {
  //   console.log(data)
  //   window.Hayk.grade = data.grade
  // })
}
```

the end link is something like this

https://inboundgrader.spacek.org/grader.php?website=www.incredo.co

I binded this function to a click. As I click on the button I can see that the request goes. In the devtools networking tab I have the file. However the console doesn't log any data and `Hayk.grade` is `undefined`

EDIT: So as suggested in the comments I split my done into success and error. And the needed result comes in the error. As this may be because of php here it is.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/javascript');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Referer: https://website.grader.com/results/{$_GET["website"]}\r\n" .
              //"Cookie: __hluid=234b284c-639f-4ff9-8dcd-4a2ced9196d4\r\n" .
              "Origin: https://website.grader.com\r\n"          
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);


$content = file_get_contents("https://api.hubapi.com/websitegrader/v1/grade/" . $_GET["website"], false, $context);
if(isset($_GET["verbose"]) && $_GET["verbose"] == 1) {
    echo $content; exit;
}

$data = json_decode($content);
echo json_encode(["grade" => $data->grade]);
exit;
```

Comment: When I do this, it gives me an object `{"grade":85}`

Comment: Do you just click on the link above? If you click on the link above yes it gives you that object. But it doesn't seem to work in a code

Comment: First of all, you should use semicolons. second of all, do you have a live demo of your code?

Comment: For the start you should try to split `.done()` method into `.success()` and `.error()` methods.

Comment: Semicolons are optional in js. No but I will make one now

Comment: So I added a working demo and also split done into success and error and this strange thing happens that it works on error with a result 200 OK? What the hell?

Comment: what does the php code look like? Are you sending a success message with the request?

Comment: I don't know I didn't write the php. So it is because of php?

Comment: I got the php. I'll put it in the question.

Comment: Put the php into the question.

Comment: You are setting incorrect header for Content type